# Id requests that admit they might be looking for non-anime

Tags: discussion

Recently I've seen a few id requests that say right in the question something like "By the way, this might not be anime." Usually they think it might be a Western cartoon. In one case the OP thought what he was looking for might be either Chinese or Russian (which is extra hard to decide on, because Chinese animation would be on-topic but Russian animation would be off-topic).

The first few were all horrible anyway, so I voted to close them as not meeting our minimum guidelines, but the last one I reviewed looked like an acceptable id request, except that the last sentence was "Also this might be an English-language cartoon." I skipped it since I wasn't sure what to do with it.

The problem here is that we're not a general purpose media identification service; Western cartoons and comic books are outside of our scope. If someone showed up here asking a question about Scooby Doo, we'd close it right away. In these cases, the OP *thinks* it might be anime, but also *thinks* it might not be, so it *might* be on-topic, or it *might* not be.

What do we want to do with these?

---

Note: Sometimes the OP doesn't say the show might be non-anime, but it turns out what they're looking for isn't anime. We can't do anything about that. This is only about cases where the OP actually writes in the question "This might not be anime" or includes a picture or something indicating that it's probably not anime.

Comment: here is an [example](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30138/tv-show-anime-with-horse-like-creatures-used-in-and-outside-of-races)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendations:

If the question doesn't meet our minimum standards, we should vote to close on that basis.

If it's about a work of animation and seems like a not utterly horrid question, migration might be an option. Science Fiction and Fantasy and Movies and TV both will take questions on Western animation. They probably don't have the same level of expertise that we do in identifying anime, but if the OP can't even remember whether what they're looking for is anime, they've come to the wrong site.

If it's about a manga that might be a Western comic, that could also potentially go to SF&F.

Any question that meets the minimum guidelines and can't be migrated should be closed as "Not about anime or manga."

Eventually, as people start to catch on to what we're doing, they'll probably stop saying it might not be anime and claim to be sure it was anime, even when they're really not sure. Of course, this will be just another of the manifold ways that people find to write awful questions, and there's nothing we can do about it. But we might as well do something with questions that straight up admit that what they're looking for might be outside our scope.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go ++